# How can I write an uppercase script L? (ℒ)

Tags: symbols

This is the symbol...

[image]

It's like a uppercase and cursive l.

Comment: Quick tip: you can use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to look up symbols, which in this case leads to `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and `\mathscr{L}`.

Comment: As the comment @TorbjørnT. should solve it, I closed as a duplicate to the general approach question. So later people are lead to that one, instead of having 1000 answers, one per question for each possible symbol. ;-)

Comment: @cursolloonline: it is very close to the `boondox` font, for which there is a package on CTAN

Answer (score 4):

It is very close to the `boondox` calligraphic font:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{boondox-cal}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}%

$ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\mathbf{Boondox:}}\\
\verb+ \mathcal + & \verb+ \mathbcal + \\[6pt]
     \mathcal{L l} & \mathbcal{L l}
    \end{array} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do I find package boondox-cal? Not available on ctan.org.